# How to upload file to stream from swagger?

Tags: file-upload, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I was wondering how you would generate the swagger UI to upload a file as a stream to the ASP.net Core controller.

Here is a link describing the difference between uploading small files vs. big files.

Here is the link of describing how to implement the upload for a small file, but doesn't elaborate on how to implement a stream.

https://www.janaks.com.np/upload-file-swagger-ui-asp-net-core-web-api/

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any capability to work with `Stream` type(s) on the request parameters directly, but the `IFormFile` interface stipulates the ability to work with streams.  So I would keep the `IFormFile` type in your request params, then either:

- Copy it in full to a memory stream **OR**
- Open the stream for read

In my case I wanted the base 64 bytes in full (*and my files are only a few hundred kbs*) so I used something like this:

```
string fileBase64 = null;
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    model.FormFile.CopyTo(memStream);
    fileBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
}
```

The `MemoryStream` is probably not appropriate in your case; as you mentioned large files which you will not want to keep in memory in their entirety.

So I would suggest opening the stream for reading, e.g.:

```
using (var fileStream = model.FormFile.OpenReadStream())
{
    // Do yo' thang
}
```